# return file address using PHP and Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have my PHP file like this:

```
<?php
function getDirContents($directories, &$results = array()){

    $length = count($directories);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {

    $files = array_diff(scandir($directories[$i]), array('..', '.'));;
    foreach($files as $key => $value){
        $path = $directories[$i].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value;
        if(is_dir($path)) {
          getDirContents([$path], $results);
        } else {
          $directory_path = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
          $results[] =  'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . str_replace($directory_path, "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) .$path;
        }
    }

    }

    return $results;
}

echo json_encode(getDirContents($_POST['directories']));
```

And I have a ajax call like this hitting the above PHP file:

```
function getURLs(directories) {
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'https://localhost/preload.php',
            data: {id: "testdata", directories: directories},
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
                // here is the result
                console.log(result);
            },
    });

}
```

As you see using the above code we're able to retrieve all file addresses of the given array of folders on server for instance if there are two files named `1-1.mp3` and `sample.png` on folder `https://localhost/sources/folder` then we can get this from the Ajax call:

```
getURLs([sources/folder]); 
// returns : ['https://localhost/sources/folder/1-1.mp3', 'https://localhost/sources/folder/sample.png']
```

The function works fine if you give it an array of folders to search but if you give it a file address it won't return a result and that's the issue

```
getURLs([sources/folder/1-1.mp3]); //returns nothing
```

I expect the above function to return the file addresses too **if exist of course**:

```
'https://localhost/sources/folder/1-1.mp3'
```

So the final function will return addresses of the ***array*** of **files** and **folders** which **exist** on the server. (we want to add the **file search** functionality as the **folder search** is working correctly)

How can we modify the PHP code to do so?

Comment: Can you show us a snippet of the POST request you are sending in the ajax function?

Comment: I don't get your meaning?

Comment: `scandir()` only works with local directories, you can't use it with HTTP URLs.

Comment: The HTTP protocol doesn't have any mechanism for listing directory contents.

Comment: I use HTTPS and I get all the files and contents of the given array of folder right now I want to get the same result if I pass a file too!!

Comment: I have tested my code both on server using https and localhost with https... and for searching folder contents it works..

Comment: Please there should be a solution :(

Comment: When you pass it a file, it returns nothing I think because you're passing the filename into scandir, and scandir clearly only works with folders. You need to do something to detect that it's a file first - maybe check if it has an extension or something. Although to be honest, if you already know the folder path and the filename then you basically already know the URL anyway, so I'm wondering if there's really any point in implementing this.

Comment: @ADyson preferable to use [`is_file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php), rather than checking for an extension.